# Docker permission denied - apache image - Hello World

Tags: apache, docker, permissions

Docker file is as follows:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

Ran docker commands:

```
docker build -t hello-world .
docker run -p 80:80 hello-world
```

Project structure:

```
projectRoot
         Dockerfile
         src/index.html
```

What is causing permission denied when I do http://localhost:80

```
172.17.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2020:19:05:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 490 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
172.17.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2020:19:05:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 490 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
[Wed Apr 08 19:05:00.837027 2020] [autoindex:error] [pid 17] [client 172.17.0.1:40036] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Wed Apr 08 19:05:00.894055 2020] [autoindex:error] [pid 17] [client 172.17.0.1:40036] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Answer (score 0):

`ADD` will copy the contents of your local directory to `/var/www/html` and `COPY` will copy the whole folder to `/var/www/html` so apache won't find the index.html because it will be here `/var/www/html/src/index.html`

Edit the dockerfile to be like that

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
ADD src /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: If that was the case then it should have given me 404 not found, not 403.

Comment: because the docker image of php:7.2-apache doesn't have a default index.html so the server doesn't find it and it throws that error, have you tried my answer ?